# Postgres database giving Cannot establish a connection erorr

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am receiving an error that shown in below, when l try to connect my  PostgreSQL database

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres using org.postgresql.Driver (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres ")

Comment: @Diya ... er, what? Why did you edit the question to undo the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

You haven't set a password for the user `postgres` or you are supplying the wrong password.

See:

- [Client Authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)
- [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: @MehmetHikmet Well, it's one of the two. Show your `pg_hba.conf`. Did you set a password on the `postgres` user? If so, what commands exactly did you use to do so? Edit your original question and comment here when done.